# Access point layer representation in QGIS with pyqgis

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, style

I am exporting the style of a categorized point layer with QGIS:

[image: layer table with common sizes and different representation in the map]

unfortunately my code only extract the size of the symbol in the definition of the properties of the layer but not the representation in the map...
here is a working code:

```
canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
allLayers = canvas.layers()
i = allLayers[0]
iter = i.getFeatures()
provider = i.dataProvider()
attrvalindex = provider.fieldNameIndex(i.rendererV2().classAttribute())
categories = i.rendererV2().categories()
color_str = []
radius_str = []
transp_str2 = []
transp_str = str(1 - ( float(i.layerTransparency()) / 100 ) )
for feat in iter:
    fid = feat.id()
    attribute_map = feat.attributes()
    catindex = i.rendererV2().categoryIndexForValue(str(attribute_map[attrvalindex]))
    if catindex != -1: 
        color_str.append(str(categories[catindex].symbol().color().name()))
        radius_str.append(str(categories[catindex].symbol().size() * 2))
        transp_str2.append(str(categories[catindex].symbol().alpha()))
    else: 
        color_str.append('#FF00FF')
        radius_str.append('4')
        transp_str2.append('1')
```